# Print specific columns after performing groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                   target   (valuation, sum)  (trade_delta, sum)
trade_id symbol                                                               
6        BIDU      123                  -161              -0.094
7        GLD       557                   -76               0.150
8        ORCL      867                    64              -0.054
10       SPY       425                   -14               0.073 
11       XOP       861                    -8              -0.057
4        SPY       157                    12               0.073
```

The actual dataframe consists of many more columns, so I just want to print the above columns. For some reason it only works when I don't include the target column. ie: the following works:

```
print(df[[('valuation', 'sum'),
          ('trade_delta', 'sum')]])
```

However if I try to also print the target column:

```
print(df[['target',
          ('valuation', 'sum'),
          ('trade_delta', 'sum')]])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Presumably this has something to do with the fact that this df was created by first doing a groupby+aggregate sum,...then merging it with a different dataframe. That is why the target column is not a tuple like the other ones.

I've checked the datatypes of each column using `df.dtypes` and all columns are float64. I have absolutely no idea why I can't print the target column along with the others.

Also, it works correctly when I print the entire dataframe, or when I print specific columns which don't include the target column. The only time there is an issue is when I try to print specific columns which include the target column (as per the above example)